# Javascript recursive object iteration generating form elements names

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, recursion, logic

I have an AJAX response which contains an object storing all my form elements structure with their respective error messages (if any).
This object structure is built as it follows:

```
var obj = {
    'entity1': { //Entity
        'attribute1': { //Field
            'isEmpty': "This value is required" //rule with error message
        },
        'attribute2': { //Field
            'isEmpty': "This value is required" //rule with error message
        }
    },
    'entity2': { //Entity
        'attribute1': { //Field
            'isEmpty': "This value is required" //rule with error message
        },
        'attribute2': { //Field
            'isEmpty': "This value is required" //rule with error message
        }
    }
};
```

All these fields are stored in the form surrounded by a main entity as it follows:

```
<input name="mainentity[entity1][attribute1]" />
<input name="mainentity[entity1][attribute2]" />
<input name="mainentity[entity2][attribute1]" />
<input name="mainentity[entity2][attribute2]" />
...
```

Basically, what I need is to iterate this object assembling the name of the inputs to be able to find them with jQuery, so I could add their respective error messages to the DOM.

I tried to create this function in javascript:

```
var prefix = 'mainentity', inputs = {};
function iterate(obj, partialName, isChild) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            switch (typeof obj[property]) {
                case 'string':
                    if (!inputs.hasOwnProperty(partialName)) {
                        inputs[partialName] = [];
                    }
                    inputs[partialName].push(obj[property]);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (isChild) {
                        partialName += '[' + property + ']';
                    } else {
                        partialName = prefix + '[' + property + ']';
                    }
                    iterate(obj[property], partialName, true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
iterate(obj);
console.log(inputs);
```

I'm basing on the attribute's type. If `string`, so it's a message. Otherwise it is a field that needs to be considered in the recursion. I tried to use the flag `isChild` only to know when exactly I would break the `partialName` and start over as a new attribute.

The problem is that the end result is becoming like this:

```
{
    'mainEntity[entity1][attribute1]': ["This value is required"],
    'mainEntity[entity1][attribute1][attribute2]': ["This value is required"], //wrong result, attribute1 shouldn't be here
    'mainEntity[entity2][attribute1]': ["This value is required"],
    'mainEntity[entity2][attribute1][attribute2]': ["This value is required"], //wrong result, attribute1 shouldn't be here
}
```

And I expect this:

```
{
    'mainEntity[entity1][attribute1]': ["This value is required"],
    'mainEntity[entity1][attribute2]': ["This value is required"], //No attribute 1 here
    'mainEntity[entity2][attribute1]': ["This value is required"],
    'mainEntity[entity2][attribute2]': ["This value is required"], //No attribute 1 here
}
```

I understand the problem. The `isChild` flag only works for higher levels, and considering that in my logic everything starting from the recursion would be a child, the `partialName` is not working properly.

How can I make this function work as I expect? I mean, how could I know the correct time to break the partial name into new inputs rather than concatenating to wrong previous fields, and make it work to any case with N nested response object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alternative loops recursively and concatenates every newly found key from an object.

```js
var obj = {  'entity1': {    'attribute1': {       'isEmpty': "This value is required1"     },    'attribute2': {      'isEmpty': "This value is required2"     }  },  'entity2': {  'attribute1': {       'isEmpty': "This value is required3"  },    'attribute2': {     'isEmpty': "This value is required4"   }  }};

function loop(o, currentPath, result) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (typeof o[k] === 'string') result[`${currentPath}`] = [o[k]];
    else loop(o[k], `${currentPath}[${k}]`, result);    
  });
}

var result = {};
loop(obj, 'mainEntity', result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great and simple solution, thank you very much! I just made some small adjustments to fit cases where an input has more than one message!